# Design Layout Changes do not appear in app

Tags: basic4android

I've been trying out the designer for a while now but I'm thinking of giving up. The problem is that when I move or resize objects in the design window nothing changes in the app. I can't see why this would be the case as it would seem to make the designer redundant. I can only assume that I've missed something fundamental.

I've been able to add an image to a button but moving items seems to have no effect.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I tested your project. Your layout includes two variants. When I changed the layout of the correct variant it changed the runtime layout as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure what you mean by two variants in this context and so I don't know what the correct variant is. Having said that I created the app from scratch and and so far it has non of the problems. I suspect **my lack of knowledge** of this environment is the real problem. I started this app to test some ideas and found I have learnt enough to justify starting from scratch to apply some fundamental changes. Thanks again Erel.

Comment: You have probably created an additional layout variant by mistake. You can see it in the visual designer. There is a small list near the bottom right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are saving and loading the correct layout?
If you resize/move anything in the designer it should reflect in the app at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, well I do use the save in the designer and in the app in the sub - Sub Activity_Create(FirstTime As Boolean) I use Activity.LoadLayout("MainLayout") and the file is called mainlayout.bal and has the right date time stamp so I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Try saving the layout file with a new name and load the new file. Maybe you are somehow referencing and older file.

Answer (score 0):

It's may not help here, but you should be consistent with case,  If your layout file is mainlayout.bal then you should use Activity.LoadLayout("mainlayout.bal"), it just saves the possibility of filename issues.

If you can post your project on the B4A forum (zip it from the file menu) it will be easier to help you on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're not adding constraints to your elements so they just jump to 0,0.
The position in the editor is just for illustrative purposes but if you want to position your elements you need to add constraints (if you're using a constraint layout).